# Rails destroy method on multiple objects issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am struggling with the logic and task at hand and was hoping for some input on how to tackle this.

I have an app that resembles Reddit.I have a post/comments/user/categories/vote models in my app. In my posts controller, I set-up the destroy method on posts. In my `posts#show controller`, I set it up where I show both the full post that user creates and the comments that many users can create. In my `Users controller` in the show method and view, I display each users comments and posts so my question is, if a user deletes their post and that post had comments, how do I go about deleting both the post and all of its associated comments. Right now, I deleted a post that had some comments from the original user of the post and I'm getting a `NoMethodError in Users#show` with an `undefined method`title' for nil:NilClass`.

Well the class is obviously `nill` because its empty now that I deleted the post that was commented on by the user as well. Any help?

the exact error is in my `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` on the `<p>commented on <em><%= link_to comment.post.title, post_path(comment.post) %></em></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dependent: :destroy` in the association between posts and comments. For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now when you call `destroy` on a post, Rails will destroy the associated comments.

For more info, search for "dependent" in [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and the [associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: This is amazing, I knew there was a simpler way, thanks a lot I'll go ahead and reaad the docs